# useRef readonly value only at initialization

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Moving to functional React components, `useRef` seems to be the way mirror class level variables. Consider:

```
class Component extends React.Component<Props> {
    private readonly foo: Something<Props>

    constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props)
      this.foo = new Something<Props>(props)
    }
}
```

In this case, the value of foo can't be reassigned.

```
const Component : React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const foo = useRef(new Something<Props>(props));
    return null;
};
```

In this case, `foo.current` is mutable, since `useRef` returns a `MutableRefObject`. Also it's going to initialize each time, which I don't want. Is there something built in to have these be immutable?

Comment: No idea about immutable refs, but the way this code is written, `new Something<Props>(props)` instance is created during every render, but only the first one is stored in the ref. There's a reason they have `useRef()` always called without any arguments [in the examples](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html).

Comment: Also, there's [RefObject<T>](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L80) in react typings which is declared to have `readonly current`, so you can explicitly  declare immutable ref type for foo: `const foo: RefObject<Something<Props>> = ....`

Comment: Yeah you're right, I don't want it to reinitialize on each run. Just copied over to demonstrate what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Making it a `RefObject` would resolve that, but wouldn't resolve the multi init issue.

Comment: Kinda looks like you want to do `const foo = useMemo(() => new Something<Props>(props), []);`

Comment: Yes, that would do the job, however I'm wary of "You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee". In this case I'd like to ensure it's only ever done once.

Comment: That's a fair point. Maybe write your own hook by extending `useRef()` that takes a callback like `useMemo()` and makes that semantic guarantee?

Comment: Be warned that it is NOT an equivalent to a once-initialized class variable. useRef quietly creates a new class in your case EVERY RENDER and discards it in favour of the first one. So make sure that your classes are cheap to create else switch to `useMemo`. Wish they would document that. Imo `useMemo` is more semantic than `useState`, since memo is supposed to be readonly plus you can re-run it on dep changes (if you wish to).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hooks FAQ contains a section on [How to create expensive objects lazily](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-create-expensive-objects-lazily). You can achieve your desired effect using the [callback signature of `useState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
const Component : React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => {
    const [foo] = React.useState(() => new Something<Props>(props) as const);
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks.